# remove red border around textarea on user input (ajax loaded)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea and a button on a page like this:

```
<div id="add_comment_container">
    <textarea id="comment_field" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea>
    <button id="add_comment">Add</button>
</div>
```

If the user clicks on the Add button without entering texts in the textarea field, I display a  message and add a red border around the textarea field. What I'm trying to do is remove that border when the user starts typing into the textarea. The problem is that the textarea and the button are loaded via ajax (therefore they are add later in the DOM).

I tried to use the .delegate() function like this, but the keyup event is not even executed:

```
$('#add_comment_container').delegate('#comment_field', 'keyup', function(){
    $(this).css('border', '');
});
```

Any help please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8VFS/)**

There are two issues here. You are delegating to a nonexistent element. Use "body". Also, you need to set a different css style in order to remove the focus border, namely: `outline to 0px`

html from demo

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

js from demo

```
var response = '<div id="add_comment_container"><textarea id="comment_field" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea><button id="add_comment">Add</button></div>';
$("body").delegate('#comment_field', 'keyup', function(){
 $(this).css('outline', '0px');
});
setTimeout(function(){
   $('#main').html(response);
 },1000);
```

Comment: `#add_comment_container` is already on the page. OP simply said the textarea and the button are loaded via ajax. Why can't s/he delegate to the container? [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oteyos/1/edit)

Comment: @thomas - In fact, the container is also loaded by ajax.

Comment: The OP just says that _The problem is that the textarea and the button are loaded via ajax_ , though I see that in your example you load the container. In any case, it is the `border` which needs to be set to `0px`, not the outline. I'll remove the downvote. Sorry I didn't get to the explanation more quickly, but I had to step away for a while. What is the `setTimeout` in you fiddle supposed to do? It just looks like it runs once onload, and then...I don't get it.

Comment: @thomas - The setTimeout will ensure that the element is not present when the event is delegated. It is a testing technique. The outline is what the OP was referring to when he said border (it is the highlighted part around a textarea when it has focus).

Answer (score 0):

Setting the border to an empty value won't work. You need to set it to 'none' or another value.

Comment: Setting the border to an empty value works. The answer of Travis J is the answer to my problem

Comment: I see my issue. My jsFiddle was setting the border to red via CSS not Javascript, in which case .css('border', '') does not work. Although your original question said that only your textarea and button were loaded via Ajax, not the container div too.